# How to delete snapshot from Google Games in Android

Tags: android, google-play-games, snapshot

Im implementing the snapshots from google games to my game, but i dont want to use the interface they use, I want to implement the **open**, **update** and **delete** gamedata in my game.

For the operations **open** and **update** i have no issue and everything works perfect, but for the **delete** operation I have a problem.

Based on the samples for **open** and **update** I managed to create a code that works but just halfway:

```
//get the snapshot
String snapshotName = "My_Snapshot_0";
Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult open = Games.Snapshots.open(mGoogleApiClient, snapshotName, false).await();
if (!open.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Could not open Snapshot for update.");
    return false;
}
//delete the snapshot
Snapshots.DeleteSnapshotResult delete = (Snapshots.DeleteSnapshotResult)Games.Snapshots.delete(mGoogleApiClient, open.getSnapshot().getMetadata()).await();

if (!delete.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to delete Snapshot.");
    return false;
}
```

This code its supposed to delete the snapshot **My_Snapshot_0** and it even returns **success**, but if I try to recreate the snapshot (using the same name), an error is returned because it could not open the snapshot. This means the deleting process is missing something to work correctly.

After trying to recreate it and fail, if I do it again (repeat recreate process), then there is no error and the snapshot is created without any problem.

Its weird how the `Games.Snapshots.delete` uses an snapshot metadata instead of the snapshot.

The documentation says little about deleting and in the samples google provide there is no sample code for doing this correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the code where you open the snapshot and the error occurs?

Comment: This is actually a bug which should be fixed in the latest version of the Play Games Application. Your code should work as expected.  Can you share what version of Play Services and Play Games you have?

Comment: ianhanniballake: the code where it fails is exactly the same to the first 6 lines that i posted. Its not an error in runtime, just the `Games.Snapshots.open` function returns a NOT success.

Comment: ClaytonWilkinson: the version Im using is `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0"`

Comment: and what is installed on your device?

Comment: The Google Play Games version installed in my device is the `3.2.17 (2135827-034)`